# Error with passeportjs and sequelize on express app

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, passport.js, passport-local

I have a problem and I cannot find a similar post for my problem, I want to go on a route, I have a message "Could not read property 'findOne' of undefined" but my model is good and works, I have it have tested with findall() in the file and works ....

I use express, sequelize and passeport.js in the back-end

Thank you in advance for your help

```js
const { User } = require('../models')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const passport = require('passport')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const verifPass = (password, user) => {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.user_password)
}

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.user_email)
})

passport.deserializeUser((email, done) => {
    User.findOne({where: {user_email: email}}).then(user => {
        done(null, user)
    }).catch(err => {
        done(err, null)
    })
})

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(email, password, done) {
        User.findOne({where: {user_email: email}}).then(user => {
            if (!user){
                return done(null, false)
            }

            if (!verifPass(password, user)){
                return done(null, false)
            }

            return done(null, user)

        }).catch(err => {
            return done(err, null)
        })
    }
));

module.exports = passport
```

*The user model*

```js
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */


    static associate({ Role, Role_User }) {
      // define association here
      this.belongsTo(Role, {foreignKey: "user_role_id" })
    }
  };


  User.init({
    user_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    user_surname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    user_phone: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    user_email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        isEmail: true
      }
    },
    user_last_connection: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false
    },
    user_password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    user_function: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    user_data_hiring: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    },
    user_data_departure: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    user_notes: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    user_role_id: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: "Roles",
        key: "id"
      }
    },
    isDeleted: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',


  }, );


  return User;
};
```

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuacQ.png)

-------------------**EDIT**-----------------

fix the first error message by create method outside passport.use

```js
    const findUser = async (email) => {
        return await User.findOne({where: {user_email: email}})
    }


    passport.use(new LocalStrategy.Strategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'
    }, async (email, password, done) => {
        try {
            const user = await findUser(email)
            console.log(user)
            if (user && verifPass(password, user)){
                done(null, user)
            }else{
                done(null, false)
            }
        }catch (error) {
            done(error)
        }
    }))
```

but now an other unknow function...
[log error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2iPf.png)

I really don't understand in the doc it doesn't make sense to happen like that.

*the login controller :*

```js
router.post('/',
    passport.authenticate('local'),
    function(req, res) {
        // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
        // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
        res.json(req.user)
    });
```

-------------------**SOLUTION**-----------------

After several hours, I found that it was actually a sensible dependency to save sessions that was causing the problem: https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-session-sequelize

I replaced it with: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mysql-session and it works perfectly

Comment: I don't see an issue with the code here. Could you update your question to share the model as well?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just tested by changing findOne to findAll in the passport configuration and I still have findOne in my error log, the problem comes from elsewhere I think

Comment: Based on the error it sounds like `User` is undefined when trying the call the findOne method. You could try adding something like `console.log('inside <> cb:', User)` on the lines before findOne is called to see where the error is coming from or if `User` is undefined everywhere in the passport file.

Comment: the console.log indicates [Function (anonymous)]